# how to draw this 'UNION' shape on canvas?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a custom view on android as below.  Please anyone give me any reference.
[image: Like This Image]

Comment: `canvas.arcTo`. You need to calculate the center of the arc and the angles to the bottom two corners. It's a geometry problem. The center point is going to have a negative Y, but the amount depends on how extreme you want the curve to be.

Answer (score 0):

Here I found the solution.

```
public class BackgroundView extends View {

    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();

    public BackgroundView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public BackgroundView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public BackgroundView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, h, Color.parseColor("#21E5AD"),  Color.parseColor("#00C48C"), Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
        paint.setShader(shader);

        float horizontalOffset = w * .8f;
        float top = -h * .8f;

        RectF ovalRect = new RectF(-horizontalOffset, top, w + horizontalOffset, (float) h / 2);
        path.lineTo(ovalRect.left, top);
        path.arcTo(ovalRect, 0, 180, false);
        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```